# Drools Hard Constraint Implementation

Tags: java, constraints, drools, optaplanner

Trying to create a Java Web Application for Employee (Nurse) Rostering using Optaplanner. I want to make a hard constraint like this:

// A nurse can only work a night shift after night, i.e. two consecutive shifts can be N-X or N-N
`rule "nightOrOffAfterNightShift"
    when
        ShiftAssignment(
            $employee : employee, employee != null,
            $shiftDate : shiftDate,
            $lastShift : shift,
            $shiftType : shiftType
        )
        ShiftAssignment(
            employee == $employee,
            shiftDate.isAfter($shiftDate) == true
        )
    then
        if(shiftType != $shiftType && shift != null)
            scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -1);
end`

I have no experience in Drools, is this valid?

Answer (score 0):

1st off - I'm no Rules expert (have recently been learning some of this stuff)

Don't think you need $lastShift : shift,
You're going to use Rules to link together 2 ShiftAssignment(s)

I think you should use an sequential ID to check consecutive shifts
currently I think your rule will fire for ALL shifts after $shiftDate
which I don't think you intend

I don't think you need the if clause in your THEN section
this should be part of your condition checking in the when section
So the Then section should contain 
   inserting new knowledge into the Rules working memory
   modifying/deleting facts currently in the Rules working memory
   print statements -- if you need them (not recommended really - use changeListeners)

if(**shiftType** != $shiftType && shift != null)
It's NOT clear which of the 2 ShiftAssignment objects you think **shiftType** is from

rule "nightOrOffAfterNightShift"
    when
        sAn : ShiftAssignment(
            $idn : Id
            $employee_n : Employee, 
            $employee_n != null,
            $shift : shift,
            $shift != null, 
            $sTn : ShiftType
        )
        sAn_1 : ShiftAssignment(
            $idn_1 : Id
            $idn == $idn_1 + 1, 
            $employee_n_1 : Employee, 
            $employee_n_1 != null,
            $employee_n_1 == $employee_n,
            $sTn_1 : ShiftType, 
            $sT != $sTn_1
        )
    then
        ????Now what do you need to do here 
end

Can you share you ShiftAssignment class

I think the above finds
  shifts idn &  idn_1 where 
  same employee
  with different shiftType

hope this is close to what you're after